# Jquery looking to trigger select box change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey i i have select box with long method binded to it to its 
the select box in the html looks like this :

**HTML:**

```
<select id="select1">
  <option>First select Advertiser</option>
  <?php
     buildSelectOptionsFromPagination();  // Dynamically build the options list
  ?>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#select1').change(function(){
                alert('#select1');
                $('#innerP').remove();
                $('#innerH').remove();
                $('#waitmsg').append('  ...</h2></p>');
                $("#show_c ").attr("disabled", true);   


                 $.ajax({
                        url: 'observer.php',
                        data: "ctrl=in&v_id="+v_id,
                        success: function(data) {
                             var newData = "<option id=\"firstopt_insert\"> blah blah <\/option>" + data;
                             $('#in111').html(data);
                             $('#in222').trigger('change');

                        },
                        error: function (request, status, error) {
                            alert(request.responseText+"\nThere was an server error please refresh the page 1 ");
                        }                           
                });
            });
```

now i try to trigger this select box change method without success
from out side i trigger 2 method , 
1. select option by index with this which works great :

```
$('#select1 option')[5].selected = true;
```

2 now i want to trigger the change method method without success like this :

```
$('#select1').trigger('change');
or 
$('#select1').bind('change', function(){ ; });
```

and its just don't trigger any thing , why ?

Comment: When you say without success, do you mean select an option without triggering the method, or trigger the method without selecting an option?

Comment: select the the option is working fine 
triggering the method NOT working

Comment: So the `.change()` is working, but you don't want to or can't use that? I'm confused on what you are asking here.

Answer (score 6):

Change event is triggered when user selects an option. It's not triggered when you are setting the value via jQuery `val()` method of by setting option's `selected` attribute to true. So you have to trigger change event manually.

Your code

```
$('#select1').trigger('change');
```

should work. Maybe, it doesn't because you code raising an error. This may happen in this place

```
$('#select1 option')[5].selected = true;
```

because here you don't perform array's range checking.

Better way is to select needed option by index like this:

```
$('#select1 > :nth-child(6)').prop('selected', true);
```

This way code wouldn't crach in case if there is no 6th option.

However, this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JknhM/) , built from your example, works just fine.